# Pierce crystal oscillator

Tags: oscillator, crystal

[image]I'm trying to simulate a 16MHz Pierce crystal oscillator with the following parameters (see attached picture.) It doesn't oscillate, but when I simulate with lower capacitor values it works well.

What could cause this problem?
[image]

Comment: Your schematic shows the series capacitance as 2.86 farads. This won't be correct. Also, what inverting buffer are you using? Please also link to the crystal data sheet.

Comment: The motional capacitance is 2.86f F, i used a simple inverter (pmos/nmos) as an inverting buffer. data sheet attached.

Comment: Your schematic says 2.86F - pleas fix this and don't rely on comments for people to figure this out. This site isn't a forum. The circuit of your buffer amp is needed.